# Read Memory in SharedArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, web-worker, arraybuffer

In an attempt to parallelize treatment on large TypedArrays, I tried to use the mozilla extension named [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer).

These objects allow concurrent workers (or main thread) to handle the same memory (which is not made unavailable to caller of postMessage).

Unfortunately, it appears <strike>I can't read the memory of those objects</strike> I can't use DataViews on them.

I tried the following with [DataViews](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) to avoid entire buffer copies:

```
var arrayBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(4); // 4 bytes
var dataView = new DataView(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)); // fails with error below
// some usage here
var first = dataView.getFloat32(0)
```

which fails with the error:

> TypeError: DataView: expected ArrayBuffer, got SharedArrayBuffer

I could read the memory by making a TypedArray back from the buffer, <strike>but this would clone the memory, and therefore ruin the performance gain of sharing memory</strike> as it appears to have a small overhead, such as suggested by this [bug answer](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246597#c3) but then I have to know the type in advance.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Lars Hansen’s response at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246597#c3 seems useful for posting as an answer or update/edit to this question.

Comment: fixed question. I tested that new Float32Array() has indeed a negligeable overhead

Comment: bug is fixed in firefox 53 : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246597

Comment: @RegisPortalez After a year... wow!

Comment: [Note that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) `SharedArrayBuffer` was disabled by default in all major browsers on 5 January, 2018 in response to [Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, at least for now.

There's a related [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246597) on Bugzilla:

> The SharedArrayBuffer spec says that DataView is allowed on SharedArrayBuffer, and that SharedArrayBuffer.isView() on a DataView should return true.  Neither is the case in Firefox at the moment.